# How do I use Javascript to detect SVG Animation and Show/Hide Flash/SVG objects?

Tags: javascript, firefox, animation, svg, browser-feature-detection

I've been experimenting with creating SVG animations using SMIL.  It works fine in the latest Firefox, but of course it doesn't work in IE.  I already have a similar Flash animation.  My plan was to include both the Flash and SVG animations on a page and show/hide them based on a javascript detection.  But I'm horrible at javascript and don't really know how to do it.  I'll be using a linked .js file.  My plan is to detect whether the browser supports the feature "http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#AnimationEventsAttribute" when the page loads, and if it is supported, hide the Flash object (id="rotateFlash") and show the SVG object (id="rotateSVG").

I don't know if there's a better way to achieve what I want, and I haven't found any code online that resembles what I'm trying to achieve.  I've found show/hide javascripts, but don't know how to implement detecting that feature with them.

This code seems to at least do something, but it seems to follow the "else" command, which I guess means Firefox isn't detecting the feature as "True" (neither is IE9, but that was expected).

```
function supportsSvg() {
  if(document.implementation.hasFeature ("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#AnimationEventsAttribute", "1.0") == "true" ) {
    document.getElementById("rotateSVG").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("rotateFlash").style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("rotateSVG").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("rotateFlash").style.display = "";
  }
}
```

I don't know what else to do.  I've tried other simpler SVG features, but I get the same result.  I keep reading about Modernizr, but it seems too complicated for me.  I don't understand how, why, if it would work.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally got it to work.  After looking over the code, I had a feeling `== "true"` was unnecessary, so I deleted it.  Now it seems to be working in Firefox 13 and IE9.

```
function supportsSvg() {
  if(document.implementation.hasFeature ("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#AnimationEventsAttribute", "1.0")) {
    document.getElementById("rotateSVG").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("rotateFlash").style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("rotateSVG").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("rotateFlash").style.display = "";
  }
}
```